# transform a given array into a new array using this equation (in javascript)

Tags: arrays, transform

I am sort of new to algorithms like this and would appreciate someone helping me figure this out and what I am doing wrong... you dont necessarily have to give me the solution right away, but at least help me figure out what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction and give me some hints! :)

**Question:**

Given an array a, your task is to output an array b of the same length by applying the following transformation: 
– For each i from 0 to a.length - 1 inclusive, b[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
– If an element in the sum a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1] does not exist, use 0 in its place
– For instance, b[0] = 0 + a[0] + a[1]

**Example**

For a = [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]: 
– b[0] = 0 + a[0] + a[1] = 0 + 4 + 0 = 4
– b[1] = a[0] + a[1] + a[2] = 4 + 0 + 1 = 5
– b[2] = a[1] + a[2] + a[3] = 0 + 1 + (-2) = -1
– b[3] = a[2] + a[3] + a[4] = 1 + (-2) + 3 = 2
– b[4] = a[3] + a[4] + 0 = (-2) + 3 + 0 = 1

So, the output should be solution(a) = [4, 5, -1, 2, 1].

So this (below) is what I thought I had to do, but apparently I am wrong (if I use the input array [2, 4, 6], the solution is supposed to be b = [6, 12, 6], but instead the solution comes out to be [ 2, 6, 10 ]... can someone tell me why??

Thank you in advance! :)

```
function solution(a) {
let b = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  // start the count of each element of the new "b" array at equal to the matching element of original given "a", since that is one of the elements needed to add to each index
b[i] = a[i]
if (i-1 >= 0){
b[i] += a[i-1]
}
if (a[i+1] < a.length){
b[i] += a[i+1]
}
}
return b
}
const array = [2, 4, 6]
console.log(solution(array))
```

Comment: Line 9, you are checking the value of a[i+1] against the index. Change this to i+1 and you will be good.

Comment: Thank you stitt! It's hard not to mix the elements with the indexes in this!